# How to write a loop to format tables differently in a word document?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have been trying to find a code to format the first table of a word document a specific way and then loop through the rest of the tables formatting them another way.  I found a code that loops through all of the tables correctly, but haven't found a way to exclude the first table in order to format it differently.  This is the code that works for all of the tables

```
Sub Change_All_Tables_Formating()
Dim oTbl As Word.Table
Dim oCell As Word.Cell
  For Each oTbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
  For Each oCell In oTbl.Range.Cells
  oCell.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
  Next oCell
  oTbl.Rows(1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = wdGray25
  oTbl.Rows(1).Range.Bold = True
  Next oTbl
End Sub
```

This is the code that I am having trouble adapting to format the first table correctly.  It needs to remove the shading from the first table completely and shade the headings of the rest of the tables in the word document.  I feel that if I can learn how to do this, I will be able to adjust any of the tables that I would like and format them individually.  The number of tables vary with each document, but the first table is always the same.  I will appreciate any help that anyone can provide.

```
Sub Change_Tables_Formating()
 Dim oTbl As Word.Table
 Dim oCell As Word.Cell
 Set oTbl = ActiveDocument.Tables
 Set oTblcnt = wdDoc.Tables.Count
    For oTbl = 0 To 1
      For Each oCell In oTbl.Range.Cells
       oCell.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
      Next oCell
       oTbl.Range.Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = wdColorWhite
      Next oTbl
    For oTbl = 2 To oTblct
      For Each oCell In oTbl.Range.Cells
      oCell.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
      Next oCell
      oTbl.Rows(1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = wdGray25
      oTbl.Rows(1).Range.Bold = True
      Next oTbl
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
Sub Change_Tables_Formating()
    Dim oTbl As Word.Table, i As Long
    For Each oTbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
        i = i + 1
        If i = 1 Then
            FormatFirst oTbl
        Else
            FormatRest oTbl
        End If
    Next oTbl
End Sub

Sub FormatFirst(tbl As Table)
    Dim oCell
    For Each oCell In tbl.Range.Cells
        oCell.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
    Next oCell
    tbl.Range.Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = wdColorWhite

End Sub

Sub FormatRest(tbl As Table)
    Dim oCell
    For Each oCell In tbl.Range.Cells
        oCell.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    Next oCell
    tbl.Rows(1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = wdGray25
    tbl.Rows(1).Range.Bold = True
End Sub
```